# Sidebar hides on scroll in phone

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website where the left sidebar hides at widths less then 768px. 
At less then 768px it is positioned absolutely with left: - 230px, so it is not visible.
OnClick - left:0px - and you the sidebar appears. 
Everything works smooth and nice in the browser on my computer. But when you open the page on the phone and try to scroll down with the sidebar open it disappears and I can't figure out why.

This is a live sample of the website:
http://ostapenko-photo.com/e-dinar/

This is the jquery I use to show-hide the sidebar:

```
$('#sidebarMobileButton').click(function() {
      if($('#sidebar').css('left') == '0px'){
        $("#sidebar").css('left', "-230px");
          $('#sidebarMobileButton').removeClass( "fa-angle-double-left" ).addClass( "fa-angle-double-right" );
      } else {    
          $("#sidebar").css('left', "0px");
          $('#sidebarMobileButton').removeClass( "fa-angle-double-right" ).addClass( "fa-angle-double-left" );  
      }
    });
```

Comment: Try to add an alert in the `click` function and see if the _alert_ shows up. If so, you need to check why. If not, probably there is another function that hides the sidebar.

Comment: Can't you just use display:none, display:block on #sidebar instead of positioning it in different x-positions?

Comment: I tried it (display:block and display: none; - still hides it on the phone on scroll)

Comment: Does it work with the above jQuery not active?